# UITableView fails to load images for first two cells

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

> I have a UITableView in which each custom cell (created in storyboard) contains a UIImageView that is asynchronously populated with an image from a custom object (`object.image`). Also, the TableView shows different content depending on the state of a UISegmentedControl that has two states (toggling the control triggers `reloadData` and the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method gets data from a different array).
>
> Ordinarily the setup works as expected. However, if I scroll down in the TableView and then toggle the SegmentedControl, the first two cells don't load their images (but the labels in the cells load fine). It appears that the ImageView is occasionally `nil`. Scrolling down past the cells and then back up causes the image to load normally.

Relevant Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Get the cell
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomTableViewCellIdentifier"];
        if (segmentedControlPosition1) {
            //Get the object containing all the data.
            myObject = [firstObjectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            //...Update cell labels...

            [cell.myImageView setImage:nil];
            
            //Asynchronously retrieve and conditionally populate the event cover image to optimize rapid scrolling in large table.
            //Fetch image data on secondary, asynchronous thread.
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
                UIImage *image = myObject.coverImage;
                if (image) {
                    //Update the UI on the primary thread.
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        //Verify that the cell is still visible.
                        if ([[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] containsObject:indexPath]) {
                            //Retrieve the cell (cell may have changed during async processing).
                            CustomTableViewCell *correctCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];;
                            [correctCell.myImageView setImage:image];
                            NSLog(@"Loaded image successfully: %i, %@, %@, %@", indexPath.row, image, correctCell.myImageView, correctCell.myImageView.image);
                            NSLog(@"%@",);
                            [correctCell setNeedsLayout];

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            
        } else {

            //...do exactly the same thing just get the data from a different array...
        }
        
    }
    return cell;    
}
```

**My `NSLog` statement reveals that sometimes, (for instance after scrolling down a bit and then toggling the SegmentedControl), `correctCell.myImageView` is `nil`. Again, all of the labels in the same cell populate just fine.**